# Android TV, remote control listener

Tags: android

Is there any way to detect a long press listener on a Remote Control for Android TV.?

I am creating a Launcher for android TV , and i need to add a functionality where the launcher must detect a long key listener of Remote Control and do some action.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: can you please tell how you get the tv remove key listener

Comment: what is your answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you ned to override/hook all of the Keyboard functions and you will be good to go

Comment: can you please tell how you get the tv remove key listener

Comment: @Ajay Venugopal, so how ?